# The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

When i follow the url http://youtuna.in it shows an internal server error.So i contact to hosting provider regarding this they said it's a script problem and developer says it's a server problem.Please anyone clear me Whats the acutall problem.I m new in this.

Comment: Please show me your .htaccess file

Comment: Thats a problem the developer not make any htaccess file.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I can't help up you.

Comment: The problem is with my addon domain and below i provide you the htaccess of  my main domain when this htaccess file on the addopn domain youtuna.in shows internal server error.But youtuna.in has no htaccess file.

Comment: Main domain htaccess file code `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png|install|sitemap.xml|robots.txt|update_database)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
AddHandler send-as-is .asis
`

Comment: Please check up my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer this question

Your code is:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png|install|sitemap.xml|robots.txt|update_database) 
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f 
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
<Files 403.shtml> 
order allow,deny allow from all </Files> 
AddHandler send-as-is .asis
```

For a reason like on [What is this file in .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452892/what-is-this-file-in-htaccess) you can remove the code as follow:

```
<Files 403.shtml> 
    order allow,deny allow from all </Files>
```

Then I think you can access your website again as I was tried it on my localhost and then I can accessed it too.
You can inform to you webhosting company to confirm the existence of code as follow on your .htaccess file because of some people think it's a XSS backdoor program (https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/files-403-shtml-order-allow-deny-allow-from-all.2748859/#post-19140446)

I hope this answer can help up you.

Comment: I create one project on file managing and downloading. But the file is download directly when user follow the download link.so i want to create download page like this http://veno.es/filemanager/?dl=4eceed883345d041634f5b21136b807c 
here is my downloadfile.php code https://pasteshr.com/EDM4cRSx8g

Comment: If you want to ask a solution for a new code, please create new question by click https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask